# Output is incorrect and cannot find error in code. kochans book on C

Tags: c

I am working to learn C with Stephen Kochans book Programming in C.  I am having an issue with the program on page 82.  The program takes a mathmatical expression and solves it.  My problem is with the final else statement, which is intended to notify the user if they input an invalid character.  When I run the program, I receive a long number, not the statement "Uknown operator" that I have programmed.

I am working in Codeblocks.  Ive checked the program a few times against the book (its written letter for letter).  Any input would be great.  Right now i suspect something with the compiler that I am overlooking or unaware of.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)

{
float value1, value2;
char operato;

printf ("Type in your expression.\n");
scanf ("%f %c %f", &value1, &operato, &value2);

if (operato == '+')
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
else if (operato == '-')
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
else if (operato == '*' )
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
else if (operato == '/' )
    if (value2 == 0)
        printf ("Division by zero.\n");
    else
        printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
else
    printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: can you mention the input which is causing the issue ?

Comment: Works OK for me. Please include the exact input you are giving to cause the unexpected output.

Comment: @HowChen there is one else for `0` division, and one for `invalid operator` it's just bad indentation.

Comment: @iharob, then I suggest we add **braces**, even there is only one line after `if/else`, or keep them in one same line

Comment: Missing `#include <stdio.h>`?  (Not likely)   In any case, check the return value from `scanf()`.

Comment: after adding the line: '#include <stdio.h>'  the program worked perfectly.  Without that header file, there were several compiler warnings raised and the resulting program failed in the manner you noticed.

Comment: @HowChen keep them in one same line is worst, just indenting it is Ok.

Comment: welp, adding braces certainly worked.  Does the text contain an error, or is this an example of the variation in systems?

Comment: @JerrySingh the braces had nothing to do, it's just that the program is not handling the case of invalid input, and it's invoking undefined behavior in that case.

Comment: @JerrySingh also, to avoid such mistake as forgetting to include a header file, use compiler warnings, it would warn you about implicit declaration of `scanf`. I never think of this problem because it never happens to me, I always compile with warnings ON.

Comment: #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>   was included at the head of the program, sorry should have included it below.  warnings are on.

Answer (score 2):

You must check the return value of `scanf`, it returns the number of arguments matched, very likely it's failing to match one of them, and a garbage value is being printed.

Try this

```
int main(void)
{
    float value1, value2;
    char operato;

    printf ("Type in your expression.\n");
    if (scanf ("%f %c %f", &value1, &operato, &value2) == 3)
    {
        if (operato == '+')
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
        else if (operato == '-')
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
        else if (operato == '*' )
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
        else if (operato == '/' )
            if (value2 == 0)
                printf ("Division by zero.\n");
            else
                printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
        else
            printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
    }
    else
        printf ("Invalid expression.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

I would prefere a switch, it would make the code clearer

```
int main(void)
{
    float value1, value2;
    char operato;

    printf ("Type in your expression.\n");
    if (scanf ("%f %c %f", &value1, &operato, &value2) == 3)
    {
        switch (operato)
        {
        case '+':
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
            break;
        case '-':
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
            break;
        case '*':
            printf ("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
            break;
        case '/':
            if (value2 == 0)
                printf ("Division by zero.\n");
            else
                printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
            break;
        default:
            printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
        }
    }
    else
        printf ("Invalid expression.\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: yea the switch is the next exercise :)

Comment: @JerrySingh the braces where not the problem, the program was the same with or without them, and did you by any chance read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: yes i read that.  still unclear what the problem is, since the program does work with the curly braces, and doesnt without.  When putting the code into stack overflow I left off the headers, they existed in the original program.

Comment: @JerrySingh explain doesn't work, I can't make it faile, without the braces, and there is absolutely no diference, the braces are required when multiple statements follow the if, but not in this case.

Comment: the output was junk.  I think this is a compiler thing, I had a similar issue on a later problem.  it was resolved after retyping sections in (identically).  Now the above code, which had been copied directly from codeblocks, is functioning.

Comment: Also, as a noob i cant propose a tag, but ive found a number of users who have questions related to this book (Kochan Programming in C), perhaps it would be useful to add a tag for Kochan to orgnize questions related to this introductory text

Comment: @ iharob yes, the code in my question.  Please note, id edited the code to reflect the header files, but it is otherwise identical.

Comment: @JerrySingh it's not a bad Idea to have the tag, but I have no idea how to do that, nor if my reputation points are enough for such privilege, and yes your code should run correctly provided the input is correct, otherwise it will fail, for example try inputing characters instead of digits. The junk comes from something called _undefined behavior_, caused by the values of the variables passed to `scanf` not being initialized.

Answer (score -1):

you should use curly braces :

```
else if (operato == '/' )
if (value2 == 0)
printf ("Division by zero.\n");
else
printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
else
printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
return 0;
```

when using nested control statements the indentation becomes important , you can solve this by adding curly braces :

```
else if (operato == '/' ) 
{
    if (value2 == 0)
        printf ("Division by zero.\n");
    else
        printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
}
else
    printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
return 0;
```

Answer (score -1):

Switch case is nothing but a alternate form of if/else. Put a bracket in the last else if .
I have tried to test the code in different test cases . Code is working fine for me.[image]

```
int main(void)

{
float value1, value2;
char operato;

printf ("Type in your expression.\n");
scanf ("%f %c %f", &value1, &operato, &value2);

if (operato == '+')
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 + value2);
else if (operato == '-')
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 - value2);
else if (operato == '*' )
    printf ("%.2f\n", value1 * value2);
else if (operato == '/' )
    {
    if (value2 == 0)
        printf ("Division by zero.\n");
    else
        printf ("%.2f\n", value1 / value2);
    }
else
    printf ("Unknown operator.\n");
return 0;
}
```